# Why Vegito chose to use kaioken and not super saiyan blue evolution to increase his power?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

When fighting with Cumber, Vegito used Kaioken to increase his power. But now Vegeta has shown he can use Super Saiyan Blue Evolution at will in Dragon Ball Heroes. Since Kaioken stress the user body, why Vegito chose to use kaioken and not Super Saiyan Blue Evolution when fighting with Cumber? It was stated that for the canon main continuity, Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken x20 is equally strong to Super Saiyan Blue Evolution transformation

Comment: SSBE also drains the user maybe not as much. Also other factors such as ki control or even what the fusion is able to do may have played part.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any particular reason, however, the only thing which makes logical sense is the fact that:

- SSBE was designed to be a Vegeta exclusive form similar to Ultra Instinct which as of now seems to be a Goku exclusive form or even SSJ3 which as of now is only a Goku exclusive form.
- We haven't witnessed a Goku+Vegeta fusion utilizing the SSJ3 form.
- Kaioken is a technique and similar to instant transmission which the fusions are capable of using. So it would make more sense for them to use techniques instead of a character exclusive form.
- Based on my previous point, it would be also interesting to note that based on the nature of Kaioken used with Super Saiyan Blue, ideally, it should be stackable even on top of SSBE as the form is simply an evolved state of Super Saiyan Blue. Which only leads to the conclusion that the fusion was utilizing Kaioken simply as a technique during the course of the fight.

Comment: That said, Gotenks is precedent for a form achieving a transformation that not only one, but both members of the fusion cannot achieve.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Agreed. That would make sense in a way as a fusion is much more powerful and capable of generating greater energy and hence, be able to transform into a higher form.

Answer (score 0):

This may be attributable to the mindset of the fusion vs. the mindset of the form.

Goku's UI is, as the name indicates, a pure instinct based form that doesn't rely on active strategy or emotion.  It is noted that it's pretty inimical to Vegeta, who is a very non-instinctual and cerebral, yet still emotional fighter.  So a fusion that combines both Goku and Vegeta seems unlikely to access UI.

SSBE is the flipside to Goku's UI, utilizing Vegeta's more cerebral and emotive nature and eschewing the calm, instinctual nature used for UI.  For much the same reasons that UI is unlikely to be used, SSBE is also probably hard to access: half of the fusion is just intrinsically unsuited to the transformation.

Kaioken, however, is a technique based on energy control.  Both Vegeta and Goku had to drastically improve their energy control in order to make SSB alone more efficient and potent.  They remark at various points that SSB is very much a form that is all about energy control.  As such the Kaioken technique is well-suited to the fusion, as both the Vegeta and Goku halves have both extensively trained their energy control.

Comment: This is incorrect. The SSBE form wasn't incorporated as a variant to Goku's UI. As O.P said, it was indicated to create a balance between Goku and Vegeta as the former had access to the Super Saiyan Blue + Kaioken form. Also, concluding that tapping into SSBE is difficult simply based on the fact that tapping into UI is, doesn't make much sense. The latter has been stated to be a level of power which even the Gods struggle to achieve. The SSBE form is an enhanced SSJB form, much like SSJ2 is to SSJ.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 I never said it was a variant. So I have no idea what you're going on about.

Comment: @zibdawa timmy In your answer, you say "SSBE is the flipside to Goku's UI and has to do with something related to Vegeta's more cerebral and emotive nature", which isn't really the case.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 You seem to be thinking flipside means some sort of literal in-universe mechanical thing, rather than the obvious metaphorical sense.  They fight differently.  They have evolved differently, with forms that suit their particular natures.

Comment: "They have evolved differently, with forms that suit their particular natures." This is incorrect. Ultra Instinct was a state both Goku and Vegeta were trying to attain and the formed got it first(on account of being the mc and being superior to the latter in many ways which help with regard to the technicality of the transformation). Vegeta's evolution was simply to scale him to SSJBKKGoku. In a realistic world, Goku shouldn't have any difficulty tapping into SSBE as well. However, since he has KK already, they simply made it a variation for Vegeta who cannot use KK.